# How can I create a generic property in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

In Swift, we can create a generic property like:

```
class MyClass<T: MyOtherType where T: MyProtocol> {
    var property: T
}
```

How is it possible in Objective-C?

Comment: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/generics-in-objective-c-8f54c9cfbce7

Comment: @Glenn it says more about how to use generic using function. I need generic property so that can use in subclass.

Comment: Google for 'light weight generics'. You can look at `NSArray` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is answer.

```
@interface myParentView< T: parentModel*> :UIView
 @property T myObject; // myObject is object of parentModel
@end
```

In all subclass:

```
@interface myChildViewOne :myParentView<childModel>
// Now myObject is object of childModel
@end
```

Obj C has complicated syntax, But we can achieve generic property like above.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming:

```
@interface MyOtherType : NSObject

// Some code 

@end

@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

// Some code

@end
```

You can do this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property MyOtherType <MyProtocol> * property;

@end
```

Syntax is `Class <Protocol>`.

It would be actually something like `Class & Protocol` type in `Swift 4+`.